# tinyMCE editor displaying html tags

Tags: html

I am using tinyMCE text editor, when i save any record it displays all the html tags for that record in the lists of records, as a temporary solution i have used post_save and rceiver object to remove the tags. Is there an easier solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

i believe not. all wysiwyg editors accepts data in the from of html. Ull need to remove the tags by urself.

U can use HTMLAgility Pack(if u r using .net) to make ur life a little easy if u want to.